# Does a file uploaded using JSP need to encode before upload?

Tags: java, jsp

If a binary file uploaded using JSP, the binary data may contain some bytes that have special meaning to some network devices and will cause problems when passing through these devices, if I upload a file like a image, do I need to encode the file with Base64 or some other encodings?

Comment: No you don't need to encode

Comment: Can you explain why, or what is wrong in my describtion about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using form in jsp i.e

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then no need of encoding.It will be send to server as Multipart file.

And it depends on your other technique what are you using to upload your file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to encode the file. When you send data using some network protocol for example TCP the data is enclosed into protocol envelope. The envelope fields may be used by network hardware for example fields like IP address could be analyzed. But you data payload is not analyzed and therefore could not have any special meaning to routers, gateways etc.